# Python mock method attributed "called" is still False after method is called

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, patch

I'm testing that a method gets called with the Python mock library. The outer method is this:

```
def get_abc():
    get_a()
    get_b()
    get_c(False)
```

The test case is like this:

```
@mock.patch('myclass.get_a')
@mock.patch('myclass.get_b')
@mock.patch('myclass.get_c')
def test_inner_methods(self, mock_meth_1, mock_meth_2, mock_meth_3):
    o = Outerclass(config_file=cfg)
    o._get_abc()
    self.assertTrue(mock_meth_1.called)
    mock_meth_1.assert_called_with(False)
```

When I follow in debug, get_c() is called successfully but the called attribute of mock_meth_1 never changes. Do I need to do more to properly mock the method?

Comment: edited: fixed patching calls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You patched `myclass.get_c` twice, so I don't know how it will behave, but it's probably not what you meant to do. Switch one of them to `myclass.get_a` and you'll probably be fine.

You might also find `mock_meth1.assert_called()` easier than `self.assertTrue(mock_meth_1.called)`.